# Is the bracha pronounced "ha-MO-tzee" or "ha-mo-TZEE"?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, bread

The blessing we say on bread, "hamotzee lechem min ha'aretz" -- on what syllable is the stress in the word "hamotzee"?

Is the bracha pronounced "ha-MO-tzee" or "ha-mo-TZEE"?

In [Psalms 104:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c26a4.htm) we find *le-HO-tzee lechem min ha'aretz*, but in [Deuteronomy 8:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0508.htm) we find *ha-mo-TZEE lecha mayim*.

Comment: It should be mileil because it is nasog achor

Comment: To make it clearer, the following word, LEchem, has stress on its first syllable. In Dt 8:15, the following word laCHEM has stress on its second syllable. The former case triggers the nasog achor.

Comment: @joshwaxman, in Deut. 8:15, the word is "Lecha," which has only one syllable (assuming that shva does not a syllable make)!

Comment: @IsaacMoses correct. But the _sh'va na_ suffices to bar the _nasog achor_ rule IINM. *Edit:* I just checked a grammar book I have at hand, and it does not list such a bar. Despite that, I suspect there may be such -- but now I'm far less confident.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I can tell, either way you accent this word is probably fine.

#### My understanding, based on Biblical grammar

My understanding is that the accent in this case goes on the '*mo*' syllable<sup>1</sup>, due to the rule of "[*nasog achor*](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%92_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8_%28%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F%29)."

This rule says that when multi-syllabic  Word A is followed (without [disjunctive cantillation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#Syntax)) by Word B, and Word B has an accent on its first (or only) syllable, then Word A's accent goes to its penultimate syllable, even if it would normally be on the last syllable. (See, for example, [Exodus 20:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0220.htm), *eh-LO-hei CHE-sef vei-lo-HEI za-HAV*. Not <s>*eh-lo-HEI CHE-sef*</s>, as that would put stressed syllables back-to-back.)

So, in the first verse you cite, [Psalms 104:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c26a4.htm)

> ‏לְה֥וֹצִיא לֶ֝֗חֶם    מִן־הָאָֽרֶץ׃ ...

Because the cantillation on "*lehotzi*" is conjuctive and the accent on "*lechem*" is on the first syllable, the accent moves from the last syllable, '*tzi*', to the penultimate one, '*ho*'.

(I'm not sure why this rule doesn't apply to the second verse you cite, since "*lecha*" has only one syllable. Maybe someone can edit this to explain.)

Similarly, in the blessing, the word "*lechem*" has an accent on the first syllable, so it pushes the accent back one spot on the previous word, "*hamotzi*."

#### Survey of Siddurim

I (and other yodeyans) looked in various different [siddurim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddur), all of which have marks to indicate when the accent is on the penultimate syllable, for printed confirmation of my understanding. Unfortunately, I found that two confirmed my observation by placing an accent mark on the '*mo*' syllable, while two did not. Perhaps someone can provide reasoning or documentation to explain the position of the two that did not.

Siddurim that confirm my understanding and place the accent on the previous syllable in this case:

- [Artscroll Siddur - RCA edition](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/SRCA.html)
- [*Siddur Rinat Yisrael*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinat_Yisrael)
- [Rabbi Sacks' British Siddur](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hebrew-Daily-Prayer-Jonathan-Sacks/dp/0007200935/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1376256984&sr=8-6&keywords=sacks%20siddur)

Siddurim that defy my understanding in this case:

- [Koren Sacks Siddur](http://www.ou.org/oupress/item/65137)
- [Hirsch Siddur](http://www.feldheim.com/the-hirsch-siddur.html)

#### Explanation from Koren

I wrote to [Koren Publishers](http://www.korenpub.com/)' Senior Hebrew Grammar Expert, Efrat Gross, asking why they don't print the accent on the penultimate syllable in this case. She replied with this answer from the Koren Siddur's chief proofreader, Chanan Ariel:

> כפי שנאמר בדברי ההסבר, מיעטנו ב"נסוג אחור" מפני שלא ברור אם יש להחיל את כללי לשון המקרא על לשון התפילה בעניין הזה. במקום שלא מסומן בו "נסוג אחור" אין פירושו של דבר שהקורא בנסיגת הטעם איננו צודק, אלא שחשבנו שאין חובה לקרוא בנסיגת הטעם. מאחר שיש כאן שינוי מלשון הפסוק שיש בו צורת מקור ולא צורת בינוני, חשבנו שעדיף שלא לקבוע מסמרות בעניין מקום הטעם.‏

Here's my translation (with some help from [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) and [Avi Shmidman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3157/avi-shmidman)):

> As is stated in the explanatory notes, we limited [application of] "*Nasog Achor*" because it's not clear if the rules of Biblical language apply to the language of prayer in this matter. Where "*Nasog Achor" is not indicated, this does not mean that one who reads with the accent pulled back isn't correct, but that we thought that there's no obligation to read with the accent pulled back. Since this text differs from the language of the [Biblical] verse, which is in the infinitive form<sup>2</sup>, rather the participle form<sup>3</sup>, we thought that it would be better not nail down the placement of the accent.

So, at least according to Koren, either way is acceptable.

---

<sup>1. Throughout this answer, I'm using the word "syllable" to refer to the Hebrew grammar concept of *tenua*, which is a little different from what "syllable" generally means. A *tenua* always contains a non-*shva* vowel and may also include adjacent letters with *shva*s under them. A *shva* never forms a *tenua* on its own; it's [always assigned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shva#Traditional_classification) to the *tenua* formed by an adjacent letter.</sup>

2. "להוציא" - "to extract"

3. "המוציא" - "The One Who extracts"

Comment: I sat down to make a clear case with backing from four sources and found myself making a compromised case with sources in both directions. "No battle plan ..."

Comment: "Perhaps someone can provide reasoning or documentation to explain the position of the two that did not." A guess: *Maybe* their position is that, although the grammar of _Tanach_ Hebrew demands that the accent be pushed back to the penult, that had changed by the time the _b'racha_ was composed.

Comment: *Nasog Achor* before a *shva na* is a sometimes-yes-sometimes-no situation.

Comment: Note that the accent in the first word won't generally jump backwards if it has to move over a shva nach (including a dagesh chazak). Also note that there are probably as many exceptions as rules when it comes to this rule.

Comment: I'd point out that when schools teach the bracha to children, it's usually taught "ha-MO-tzee", but Hebrew grammar enthusiasts will tell you that doesn't prove much ...

Comment: @Shalom, don't get me started. The way they have taught generations of people to mangle *the meaning* of words in bentching ...

Comment: @IsaacMoses "umechin mazon, le-echol briosav..." :)

Comment: @shalom veaCHAlta...uveiRACHta. tamid lo chasar laNU.

Comment: @DoubleAA, That bothers me every single time I hear the song. Also "hu nosein leCHEM l'chol basar..."

Comment: @jake "kodesh hi LAchem shabbat hamalka"

Comment: @IsaacMoses the plot thickens ... the British United Synagogue siddur, which used Lord Sacks' translation pre-Koren, has the stress mark ha-MO-tzee. Yet the Koren-Sacks doesn't ...

Comment: Interesting. This also fits with Koren's using _Kayemet_ instead of _Kayamet_ in the blessing _Emet veYatiz_. Don't extend rules of Biblical grammar without precedent.

Comment: More expressions of this policy of Koren's are described in [this Seforim Blog post](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2018/11/conservative-conversions-some.html) @Shalom

Answer (score 1):

<s>To answer the *pasuk* in *Devarim*, *nasog achor* does not apply following a *mafsik* - a break/pause, if I remember correctly, and *lecha* has a *pashta* on it, which is a *mafsik*. Since, *klalei dikduk* have you pausing anyway after a *mafsik*, there is no need fto use *nasog achor* for *tiferes Ha'kriah*. On *L'Hotzi* in *Tehilim*, the *trop* is a *maircha*, which is a *mechaber* - a connector, so *nasog achor* applies.</s>

The above is correct but irrelevant. More correctly, *nasog achor* is called when there is not enough space between the accented syllables. Since *lecha* is *milra*, there is a tenuah between the stress on *-tzee* and the stress on *-cha* so המוציא can stay *milra*. In *Tehilim*, *lechem* being *milail* would leave no space between *-cha* and *Le-*, and there is no natural pause because it is a *maircha*, so *nasog achor* activates.

Comment: Avraham, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the analysis! Shouldn't it be the trop on *hamotzi* that matters, and not that on "lecha"? In Devarim 8:15, the former has a mahpach, and the latter has a pashta, so there's no pause between them.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I mixed two things up, I will correct the answer. Thanks! I cannot upvote your comment yet, though, sorry.

Comment: So you're saying, as [msh210 did](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30391/is-the-bracha-pronounced-ha-mo-tzee-or-ha-mo-tzee#comment77114_30391) that the sheva na' under the lamed makes a tenu'a?

Comment: Not a full-fledged *tenuah* but enough of a pronounced syllable to prevent *nasog achor*. I believe we see similarly with *meteg* rules that a *shva na* can be counted as as syllable, even though it is not a *tenuah*.

Comment: This looks like a comment on... something. Can you [edit] it to clarify the relevance to the question (pronunciation of _hamotzi_ in the _b'racha_)?

Comment: Not any longer it seems. It was an answer to @IsaacMoses as to the *shva na* being a pronounced syllable enough to prvent *nasog achor* even though the *shva* is not a *tenuah*.