# Why is מקראי קדש not נסוג אחור?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation, parashas-emor

In Parshat Emor, [Vayikra 23:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> דַּבֵּ֞ר אֶל־בְּנֵ֤י יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ וְאָמַרְתָּ֣ אֲלֵהֶ֔ם מוֹעֲדֵ֣י יְהוָ֔ה אֲשֶׁר־תִּקְרְא֥וּ אֹתָ֖ם מִקְרָאֵ֣י קֹ֑דֶשׁ אֵ֥לֶּה הֵ֖ם מוֹעֲדָֽי׃

And also 23:37:

> אֵ֚לֶּה מוֹעֲדֵ֣י יְהוָ֔ה אֲשֶׁר־תִּקְרְא֥וּ אֹתָ֖ם מִקְרָאֵ֣י קֹ֑דֶשׁ לְהַקְרִ֨יב אִשֶּׁ֜ה לַיהוָ֗ה עֹלָ֧ה וּמִנְחָ֛ה זֶ֥בַח וּנְסָכִ֖ים דְּבַר־י֥וֹם בְּיוֹמֽוֹ׃

In general, when a word (קדש here) is accented *mil'el* and the previous word is connected with conjunctive cantillation (מקראי with a *munach*), the preceding word will be *nasog achor*, accented on an earlier syllable. There are rules that are exceptions to the rule, such as if pulling it back would cause consecutive accents with the second preceding word, or if it ends with כם/כן/הם/הן. This does not seem to match any of the exceptions listed in Tikun Simanim.

Why then does it not apply here?

(23:4 has a *tipcha* which is disjunctive on מקראי so you wouldn't expect it to be *nasog achor*.)

> אֵ֚לֶּה מוֹעֲדֵ֣י יְהוָ֔ה מִקְרָאֵ֖י קֹ֑דֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר־תִּקְרְא֥וּ אֹתָ֖ם בְּמוֹעֲדָֽם׃

I'm sure there are other cases where you would expect *nasog achor* and it isn't there, but i'm asking about this specifically because i feel like i have seen these words with *nasog achor* somewhere, but i can't find it right now.

Comment: Slightly related (to have a link to other _nasog achor_ questions): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43336/is-the-rule-of-nasog-achor-specific-to-the-bible

Comment: Another *Kri'ah* question! Can you explain why a *tipcha* overrides nasog achor? I've also seen it overriden when *nasog achor* would change the meaning.

Comment: @DanF tipcha is disjunctive

Answer (score 2):

According to [its Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%92_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8_(%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F)) page, Nasog Achor is not an absolute rule, and there are great numbers of exceptions that do not follow any rules that would exclude them (see the page for examples):

> נסוג אחור אינו כלל חובה ולעיתים נראה כי בעלי המסורה קבעו אותו באופן שרירותי למדי. כמעט בכל עמוד בתנך מודפס ימצאו מקרים שהיו ראויים לקבל נסוג אחור - ואין.‏

This would be one of them, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the 2nd Hebrew sentence. Is it implying that something has been published on each page of Tanac"h where *nasog achor* is (not) being used?

Comment: @DanF on almost every single page of any printed Tanach, examples of Nasog-Achor worthy cases that are not followed can be found

Comment: Hmmm ... Sounds like an "understatement". *Nasog Achor* is certainly not a given. That's what makes *kri'a* a huge challenge. If you have time, see the linked question which kazi mentioned. That one has no answer, yet.