# new artscroll siddur dikduk questions

Tags: grammar-dikduk, nuschaot, artscroll

In the new Artscroll siddurim (ie. the "WASSERMAN EDITION OF THE NEW, EXPANDED ARTSCROLL SIDDUR"), there are a few changes from the older Artscroll siddurim.

- In the new siddurim, the word "rivah" in the go'el yisrael bracha of shemoneh esrei, the accent is on the last syllable, so it is "rivAH," but in the older siddurim, it is on the first syllable, "RIVah."
- Also in the tachanun prayer, the phrase "chon om l'shimcha mikaveh," is changed to "mikavah" in the new siddurim.
- Also in tachanun, the phrase "hatei elokai ozn'cha u'shama," is changed to "u's'hma" with a sh'va na instead of a patach in the new siddurim.

Does anyone know the right girsa to these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a Rabbi and he asked a dikduk expert.  According to him, according to the most accurate rendition of the Nusach HaGra as printed in the sidur aizer eliyahu, 10th edition, the girsa is

V'riVAH

chon ohm l'shimcha m'kava

Comment: I'm fine with this answer b/c I'm giving benefit of doubt. But it raises a question and a "problem" for me. Q - is what defines a "dikduk expert" in terms of "nusach haetfillah". I'm not quite as concerned with issues in tefilla as I could envision a debate on questions that may arise during Torah reading with the requirement for accuracy is far stricter than for tefillah. The "problem" here is that the rav is making a "halachic decision" based on this advice. What has the rav decide if that person is reliable?

Answer (score 5):

1) הַטֵּה אֱלֹהַי אָזְנְךָ וּשְׁמָע is just a quote from [Daniyel 9:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3409.htm) and there is no Patach there. If you're seeing a Chataf-Patach in some editions, realize that's just an old fashioned way of indicating a Shva Na. So everyone really agrees this is a Shva Na.

2) ריבה ריב[]‏ exists multiple times in Tehillim (35:1, 43:1, 74:22, 119:154) and is always Milra.

3) It seems older Siddurim had מקוָה with a Kamatz (eg. [Beit Tefillah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23806&st=&pgnum=106)) and it was changed to a Segol for [grammatical reasons](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35686&pgnum=43) by R [Yitzchak](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91) [Satanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Satanow) in his controversial Siddur [VaYe'tar Yitzchak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23772&st=&pgnum=78).

You should really check with a rabbi who knows his grammar and Nusach before relying on this answer or on any printed Siddur.

Comment: Please note that although the prosody of the biblical precedent(s) must be informative, [it doesn't necessarily disambiguate](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30396/3) that of the word once borrowed into the _t'fila_, so the last disclaimer is particularly important.

Comment: I checked your sources in Tehillim and they are indeed all milra, but that doesn't explain why most siddurim have the accent on the first syllable, and that is in fact the accepted nusach, to pronounce it on the first syllable, I don't know why though.

Comment: @maleperson888 "the accepted nusach" Why do you speak as if there is one nusach which is accepted and you are privy to it? The world is a big place.

Comment: Because in the vast majority of siddurim the accent is on the first syllable.

Comment: @maleperson888 Have you checked the vast majority of siddurim? Or you just use the same few over and over again.

Comment: Beit Yaakov http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42759&st=&pgnum=161 and Derekh haChayim http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42979&st=&pgnum=125 with Kamatz. So too R Shabti Sofer's.