# Text differences between Torah and Siddur

Tags: grammar-dikduk

This question is based on 'Az Yashir', that we say everyday during Shacharit.

In the first picture below, inside the word circled in red, the first 'mem' has a 'Chataf patach'.

[image]
It was retrieved from https://www.chabad.org/media/pdf/263/QiNS2639457.pdf

In the second picture below, inside the word circled in red, the first 'mem' instead has a 'Shva'.

[image]
It was retrieved from https://www.770live.com/en770/siddur/siddur.htm

Does anyone know why the siddur's vowels are different?
If there is a grammatical rule that lets people use a Chataf patach and a Shva interchangeably, can you please share it?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79348/759

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77548/hataf-patah-instead-of-shva-na-in-sephardic-and-ashkenazic-tikkunim

Comment: Although I cannot, off-the-cuff, answer your question about this specific textual variation between the text of the Torah and text of the Siddur, I can point out that, in general, yes, the variation is intended. It relates to the intent of the author of the Siddur in contrast to the intent of the written Torah. See for example the famous letter of Rabbi Shimshon of Ostropoli that is read on erev Pesach, for a example of this. Rabbi Shimshon provides a detailed explanation from the Ari z'l outlining this concept in regard to the text of the Hagaddah & numerous textual variations.